# textContent not changing dom element, even it shows it is

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I'm trying to change the text value of an `option` element which is under a `select` element. It is working and not working at the same time. At first, I thought my selection is not correct, so I copied the JS Path directly using DevTool.
Let's first see what's the current value is:

```
> document.querySelector("#loc-type > option:nth-child(1)").textContent;
<- 'Select Location'
```

Cool, now let's change the value:

```
> document.querySelector("#loc-type > option:nth-child(1)").textContent = "Something";
<- 'Something'
```

Now let's make sure it got changed:

```
> document.querySelector("#loc-type > option:nth-child(1)").textContent;
<- 'Something'
```

The console is suggesting that the value has been changed but if I check on the browser, it is not changed, if I check under Elements, it is not changed. Another thing is if I change the value directly from the Elements tab, it takes effect.

Actual HTML:

```
<select name="in_loc" id="loc-type" class="someClass" data-placeholder="Species" data-issearch="true" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
</select>
```

There are other 'option' elements inside, but I think they are not relevant?

Anyway, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very basic here, so if anyone can point it out, I'll be grateful.

Comment: What you have works, [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szta867j/). It does change the text within the desired element.

Comment: Yes, it is but its not reflecting on the DOM

Comment: Try to use another option like innerHtml, and see if the problem persists, also try another browser. Perhaps you have a syntax problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: It works for me (Edge/Chrome and Firefox on Windows10). What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want set the Option `Something` you have to fetch the select container. Then you can set the option by value. like that:

```
document.querySelector("#loc-type").value = "Something";
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm not sure why it should work?

Comment: the option something ,ust exists in you select box?

Comment: Yep, well actually its value is 'Select Location', I'm trying to change it to 'Something'

`<option value="">Select Location</option>`

Comment: @Mahdi And it works?

Comment: It shows that it works, the value does get changed, it just doesn't get reflected on the DOM